# ggplot scale with Yeo-Johnson transformation

Tags: r, ggplot2, transformation

I'm trying to create a boxplot with the y-axis transformed with a Yeo-Johnson transformation. Below my code to attempt this but it returns an error, which is below the code. I wrote the code using this [LINK](https://gist.github.com/wch/3250485). For ease I use an example with the Iris dataset. Please let me know your thoughts on how to make this work.

#### The code:

```
library(scales)
library(VGAM)
trans.yeo <- function(x) {
  yeo.johnson(x, inverse = FALSE, lambda = -1.000968)
}  

back.yeo <- function(x) {
  yeo.johnson(x, inverse = TRUE, lambda = -1.000968)
} 

scale.yeo <- function() {
  require(scales)
  trans_new("yeo", transform = trans.yeo, inverse = back.yeo)
}

iris.bxp <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length, fill=Species)) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_y_continuous(trans = scale.yeo())
iris.bxp
```

(The specific transformation with the specified lambda might not make sense for the Sepal.Length variable, but it makes sense for my own data. It is just to give a usable example of the code I produced)

#### The error produced:

> Error in ans[index] <- (y[index] * lambda[index] + 1)^(1/lambda[index]) -  : 
>     NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

#### Edit:

if I first define:

```
trans_yeo <- trans_new("yeo", transform = trans.yeo, inverse = back.yeo)
```

and then replace `scale_y_continuous(trans = scale.yeo())` by `coord_trans(y=trans_yeo)` it does seem to work...